# Error: $x^2 + 1 = 0$ has solution set $\{-1;1\}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots

[image]

So, is it correct that the solution set of **$x^2 + 1 = 0$ is [-1;1]** ?

Is the error in equation development or in the solution set?

Help me, I don't know how to proceed in this question.

Comment: You can plug each of $1$ and $-1$ into the equation and find it is not satisfied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the implications are true but you are drawing the wrong conclusion. You have proved that $x^{2}+1=0$ implies $x=1$ or $x =-1$ but the converse of this implication is not true. The fact is there is no real number $x$ with $x^{2}+1=0$.

Comment: (+1) What I would have written if I had more time.

Comment: The final implication is true only if it's been established that $x$ is restricted to be a real number.

Comment: @BarryCipra Sure. I am basing my answer on the assumption that $x$ is a real number. I will wait for the OP to clarify if he is allowing $x$ to be complex.

Comment: So, the correct way would be x^2+1=0  implies x=1 or x=−1  and  empty implies  {-1;1}?

Comment: @DanielSehnColao Since neither $x=1$ nor $x =-1$ satisfies $x^{2}+1=0$ the conclusion is there is no real number $x$ satisfying the given equation.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy okay. But there is one thing that I am getting confused... If get x^{2}+1=0 implies x = 1 or x = -1, then I have   x^{2}+1=0   ⇒   x = 1 or x = -1, right?
Why does it not correct?

Comment: You could also say $x^2 + 1 = 0$ implies $x = \pi$ or $x=42$ or "$e$ is rational".  I worry this confuses rather than clarifies.   Also "$x^2 + 1= 0$ has no real solutions" doesn't really make "$x^2 + 1=0$" a false statement in the usual sense.  Proper conclusion of $x^2 + 1=0$ IMO should be "$x$ is not real" and not "I have a pink dragon eating popcorn in my brain".  That's my opinion.

Comment: @DanielSehnColao $x^2 + 1= 0 \implies x =1$ or $x = -1$ in the same sense that ($\pi$ is rational) $\implies$ (Green frogs controled the Kremlin in 65 million B.C.)  $x^2 + 1 = 0$ is impossible so it is false.  A false premise can imply *anything*.  So $x = \pi$ or $x = 10^{42}$ are just as valid conclusions.  This answer is technically correct but if I'm honest, I think it is far more harmful than helpful.

Comment: Ok, I think I got it @fleablood

Answer (score 3):

When they multiplied by $(1-x^2)$, they introduced two additional roots for the equation $\pm 1$.

Note that

$$x^4=1$$

has four roots in the complex domain which are $\pm 1$ and also $\pm i$.

Comment: I'm not sure why the other solutions are not pointing out the erroneous trick that multiplying by $x^2-1$ add extraneous solutions.  IMO that is the *entire* aspect of the problem.  So +1 to you.  Also note, even if you don't consider complex roots.  $x^2 +1=0$ has no real roots.  And $x^2 -1=0$ has two.  So $x^4 -1$ has $2$ but two came from $x^2 -1$ and zero came from $x^2+1$.

Answer (score 0):

The final implication should be "$\implies x\in\{1,-1,i,-i\}$." That is, the solutions to $x^2+1=0$ (if any) are among the elements of this set, not that *all* the elements of the set are automatically solutions of the equation.

Answer (score 0):

No.  It is not as plugging in $1$ and $-1$ will give you $(-1)^2 + 1 = 2$ and $1^2 +1 =2$.

The problem is that multiplying by $x^2 -1$ gives extraneous solutions and $1, -1$ are the solutions to $x^2 -1 =0$ which was brought in from nowhere.

This would b similar to doing this:

Suppose $(x -3)(x-2) = x^2 -5x + 6 = 0$  (So the solutions are $x = 3$ or $x = 2$.  As that is zero we multiply it by $x+3057$ So

$(x^2 - 5x+6 ) = 0$ so

$(x^2 - 5x + 6)(x+3057) = 0\cdot (x+3057)=0$ so

$x^3 - 3052x^2 -1579x +18342 = 0$

If we tried to solve $x^3 - 3052x^2 -1579x +18342 = 0$ we would get $x = 3$ or $x = 2$ or $x =-3057$.

The third solution came in when we multiplied by $x+3057$.  That is  because $x = -3057$ is a solution to $x+3057=0$.  So by multiplying $0$ by $x+3057$ we add a new solution to the problem.

So in this "false proof":

So $x^2 + 1 = 0$ has no real solutions.  (It has *complex* solutions, $x = i$ or $x = -i$ but no real solutions).

But $x^2 -1=0$ has two real solutions; $x = 1$ and $x = -1$.

By mulitplying both sides of the equation $x^2 + 1= 0$ by $x^2 -1$ we are taking all the original solutions (there are no real solutions but there were complex $x=i$ and $x=-i$) and adding the solutions $x = 1$ and $x =-1$.  So we end up with solutions $x =1$ and $x = -1$ but they were both artificially added when there no real solutions in the first place.